# Delete parent of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering how you would go about deleting a row in a table (HTML table) on the click of a button. At the moment the table is dynamically created with javascript and jQuery but I want to have a button that deletes the buttons row when selected. At the moment is this sort of what each row looks like in the table:

```
<tr><th>Some text</th><th><button type="button">Delete</input></th></tr>
```

Since each row has the same setup, is there a way to delete the parent `<tr>` of the button that was clicked without the use of id's?

Comment: the `.closest()` API is what you need - `$(this).closest('tr')` from the "click" handler for the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean*:

```
<tr><th>Some text</th><th><button class="delete">Delete</button></th></tr>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OZUlexA/1/edit)**

```
$('#table').on('click', '.delete', function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: Can't you also use `.parents('tr')`?

Comment: @bozdoz That would require extra code to make sure you're removing the first `tr` not all `tr` parent instances, but yes, you could use `.parents()`. `.closest()` is the better way to go, in my opinion.

Comment: Good call.  I never put a `tr` inside of a `tr`, but you never know what some people will come up with.

Comment: Thanks! It is exactly what I was wanting :)